How to ensure that polars creates a column of type list rather than type object
The code below will create a column called paid that looks like a list, but is an object, and thus practically useless as a column. How can I ensure that the created column is a list column rather than an object column since .cast() cannot be applied to the object column after is has been created.
import numpy as np
import polars as pl
import scipy.stats as stats

CLUSTERS = 200 
MEAN_TRIALS = 20
MU = 0.5
SIGMA = 0.1

df_cluster = pl.DataFrame({'cluster_id': range(1, CLUSTERS+1)}) 

df_cluster = df_cluster.with_columns(
    mu = stats.truncnorm(a=0, b=1, loc=MU, scale=SIGMA).rvs(size=CLUSTERS),
    trials = np.random.poisson(lam=MEAN_TRIALS, size=CLUSTERS)
)

df_cluster = df_cluster.with_columns(
    pl.struct(["mu", "trials"])
    .map_elements(lambda x: np.random.binomial(n=1, p=x['mu'], size=x['trials']))
    .alias('paid')
)

df_cluster.head()



Something seems to be up with detecting numpy arrays in this case - which is probably a "bug". When running UDFs, I've found manually wrapping a Polars Series usually avoids any issues: pl.Series(np.random.binomial(...))

you can create list() out of ndarray before returning it:
...
df_cluster = df_cluster.with_columns(
    pl.struct(["mu", "trials"])
    .map_elements(
        lambda x: list(np.random.binomial(n=1, p=x['mu'], size=x['trials']))
    )
    .alias('paid')
)

df_cluster.head()

┌────────────┬──────────┬────────┬─────────────┐
│ cluster_id ┆ mu       ┆ trials ┆ paid        │
│ ---        ┆ ---      ┆ ---    ┆ ---         │
│ i64        ┆ f64      ┆ i32    ┆ list[i32]   │
╞════════════╪══════════╪════════╪═════════════╡
│ 1          ┆ 0.508726 ┆ 25     ┆ [1, 0, … 1] │
│ 2          ┆ 0.513275 ┆ 26     ┆ [1, 1, … 0] │
│ 3          ┆ 0.57244  ┆ 22     ┆ [1, 0, … 1] │
│ 4          ┆ 0.556384 ┆ 15     ┆ [0, 0, … 0] │
│ 5          ┆ 0.51955  ┆ 15     ┆ [1, 1, … 1] │
└────────────┴──────────┴────────┴─────────────┘


As @jqurious mentioned in the comments, you can wrap the result into a polars.Series. However also specifying the return_dtype will take some of the guess work off of polars end.
import numpy as np
import polars as pl
import scipy.stats as stats

CLUSTERS = 200
MEAN_TRIALS = 20
MU = 0.5
SIGMA = 0.1

df_cluster = pl.DataFrame({'cluster_id': range(1, CLUSTERS+1)})

df_cluster = df_cluster.with_columns(
    mu = stats.truncnorm(a=0, b=1, loc=MU, scale=SIGMA).rvs(size=CLUSTERS),
    trials = np.random.poisson(lam=MEAN_TRIALS, size=CLUSTERS)
)

df_cluster = df_cluster.with_columns(
    pl.struct(["mu", "trials"])
    .map_elements(
        lambda x: pl.Series(
            np.random.binomial(n=1, p=x['mu'], size=x['trials']),
            dtype=pl.Int64
        ),
        return_dtype=pl.List(pl.Int64)
    )
    .alias('paid')
)

print(df_cluster.head())
# shape: (5, 4)
# ┌────────────┬──────────┬────────┬─────────────┐
# │ cluster_id ┆ mu       ┆ trials ┆ paid        │
# │ ---        ┆ ---      ┆ ---    ┆ ---         │
# │ i64        ┆ f64      ┆ i64    ┆ list[i64]   │
# ╞════════════╪══════════╪════════╪═════════════╡
# │ 1          ┆ 0.553375 ┆ 24     ┆ [0, 0, … 1] │
# │ 2          ┆ 0.58199  ┆ 24     ┆ [0, 0, … 0] │
# │ 3          ┆ 0.545794 ┆ 25     ┆ [0, 1, … 0] │
# │ 4          ┆ 0.501513 ┆ 18     ┆ [0, 1, … 1] │
# │ 5          ┆ 0.561322 ┆ 17     ┆ [0, 1, … 1] │
# └────────────┴──────────┴────────┴─────────────┘


In your .map_elements call, have numpy return the values as a Python list instead of as an np.array. In the former return type, Polars 0.20.25 casts properly to list[i64].
>>> df_cluster = df_cluster.with_columns(
...     pl.struct(["mu", "trials"])
...     .map_elements(lambda x: np.random.binomial(n=1, p=x['mu'], size=x['trials']).tolist())
...     .alias('paid')
... )
>>> df_cluster.head()
shape: (5, 4)
┌────────────┬──────────┬────────┬─────────────┐
│ cluster_id ┆ mu       ┆ trials ┆ paid        │
│ ---        ┆ ---      ┆ ---    ┆ ---         │
│ i64        ┆ f64      ┆ i32    ┆ list[i64]   │
╞════════════╪══════════╪════════╪═════════════╡
│ 1          ┆ 0.52546  ┆ 14     ┆ [1, 0, … 1] │
│ 2          ┆ 0.584446 ┆ 22     ┆ [1, 0, … 0] │
│ 3          ┆ 0.590928 ┆ 16     ┆ [0, 1, … 0] │
│ 4          ┆ 0.506396 ┆ 19     ┆ [1, 1, … 0] │
│ 5          ┆ 0.564219 ┆ 29     ┆ [0, 0, … 0] │
└────────────┴──────────┴────────┴─────────────┘

It looks to me like the code that pl.Series.map_elements ends up calling in Rust doesn't handle np.ndarray but does handle PyList, PyDict, and pl.Series (which declare the attribute _s) types. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/py-0.20.25/py-polars/src/map/series.rs.
